# How to use BulkDelete with auto generated key as a primary key (using Entity Framework Plus library) in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-plus, bulk-delete

I am working on a project where I have an excel sheet with some data.
I am converting it into list and mapping it into another list which is derived from table in a database using entity framework core.

Now I want to insert,update and delete the database with the list from the excel sheet.
So I am trying to use bulk operation from Entity Framework Extension library but if I have proper primary key it works fine but if I have auto generated key as primary key bulk delete does not work.
I don't know the reason for that.It does not show any errors and it does not delete any records as well.
I don't understand the problem here.

This is what I tried.

```cs
context.BulkDelete(mappedvalue, options =>
{
    options.UseAudit = true;
    options.AuditEntries = auditEntries;
});
```

This is my class.

```
public class ScTable
 {
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? EmailId { get; set; }
    public string? AppsInstalledInSystem { get; set; }
    public Int64 Autokey { get; set; }
 }
```

The below code is the sample data from my excel sheet.Here Autokey is  my auto-generated primary key in my table.

```
| UserName | EmailId             | AppsInstalledInSystem |Autokey |
| -------- | ------------------- | --------------------- | ------ |
| SS009876 | samsundar@gmail.com |   MSOffice            | 0      |
| SS009876 | samsundar@gmail.com |   VisualStudio        | 0      |
| SS009876 | samsundar@gmail.com |    SqlServer          | 0      |
| SR009754 | divyasam@gmail.com  |     VisualStudio      | 0      |
| SC009345 | venkat258@gmail.com |    SqlServer          | 0      |
| SC009345 | venkat258@gmail.com |     VisualStudio      | 0      |
```

Comment: Show entity definition, sample data which do not work. What you have shown is like, look this is documentation sample which I have tried. If BulkDelete works with PK, it will delete only records which matches with database records via PK - there are no surprises.

Comment: Also, why you have used third party library? How many records do you process? What is nature of the data?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv : Hi, I have given the sample data as you asked.I have around million data that needs to be processed.I use third party app because its hard to process million data with entity frmework core.

Comment: What are you trying to delete? What are the criteria? And why use an ORM at all, if you want to delete 1M rows? You aren't working with objects.

Comment: In any case, there's no such thing as "bulk delete", at least not in the sense of minimally logged operations. In EF Core 7 and later, `ExecuteUpdate` is used to provide the WHERE conditions used in an actual `DELETE ThatTable Where...` command. Whatever that third party library does will be *slower* than this, because there's simply no other mechanism in SQL Server itself except partition management. That third party library is closed source but what it seems to be doing is extract the PK values for those objects and then try to delete batches of them with `IN` or a table parameter

Comment: How do you determine which rows to delete? Even if that library avoids loading 2M IDs in memory, deleting 2M rows is slow. If you want to remove historical data periodically, the fast (as in milliseconds) solution is to use partitioning and truncate old partitions or swap them out to a history table. That's a metadata operation so it takes milliseconds. Check [this performance comparison](https://michalmolka.medium.com/sql-server-truncate-partition-performance-854d6e9602d3) which goes from 7 minutes for 750M rows to 0

Comment: `I want to insert,update and delete the database with the list from the excel sheet.` The normal and fast way to do this is to load the Excel data into a staging table, join with the target and INSERT/UDPATE the matching or non-matching rows. If you want to completely replace the contents of the target table though, you can use partition switching and simply swap the table data instantly

Comment: So you want to compare existing records and insert new, update old and delete not existent using key `UserName`?

Answer (score 0):

> So I am trying to use bulk operation from Entity Framework Extension library but if I have proper primary key it works fine but if I have auto generated key as primary key bulk delete does not work

My understanding is that when you use your proper key, the `Autokey` column has a value for every row. So there is no problem with using [Bulk Delete](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-delete)

However, when you use an auto-generated key, the column `Autokey` has all the value to `0` must is probably still the key you are using to match.

You need, in this case, use a custom key (might be the `Username` if unique or maybe a combination of `Username` and `Email`) with the [ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression](https://entityframework-extensions.net/column-primary-key-expression) option. The custom key must make the row unique.

```cs
context.BulkDelete(mappedvalue, options =>
{
    options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.UserName };   
    //options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.UserName, x.EmailId };
    options.UseAudit = true;
    options.AuditEntries = auditEntries;
});
```